# Is `int(int) const` a valid function type in C++23?

Tags: c++, function, std, standards, function-signature

Below is excerpted from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function):

```
template<class...>
class move_only_function; // not defined

template<class R, class... Args>
class move_only_function<R(Args...) const>;
```

I also tried the following code:

```
// ok
std::function<int(int)> fn; 

// error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
// 'std::function<void () const>'
std::function<int(int) const> fn;
```

**Is** `int(int) const` **a valid function type in C++23?**

Comment: It can be a valid function type and still not a valid argument for `std::function`

Comment: I think I understand your question, but you might want to point out that `std::move_only_function<int(int) const> fn;` does compile, and focus on asking if `int(int) const` is a valid function type. The usage of `std::function` is misleading here.

Comment: What’s the meaning of int(int) const?

Comment: And no, I don't think `int(int) const` is a valid function. The const here is what's applied to the `operator()` of the callable stored in the move_only_function. The signature (not counting cv qualifiers) is `int(int)`.

Comment: *"What’s the meaning of int(int) const"* - Something you get when decomposing `int(C::* x)(int) const`, a pointer to a member function with a const implicit object parameter.

Comment: what are you asking? Whether `int(int) const` should work for `std::function`? Why it does not work? Or whether `int(int) const` is a function type? If it is the latter, the stuff about `std::function` is somewhat confusing, its related but detracting from the actual question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, i want to know the meaning of int(int) const, and it has been well answered.

Comment: Look, it has to exist in the type system because members are funky. If you want to [be cute and use it to declare members](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dyOy2hKufq5KYxUi) as well, it's possible. It's just not something `std::function` should deal with, hence all the comments about the flaw in the test.

Comment: You could have tried eg `int(f)(int) const;` as an attempt to declare a function, its a syntax error https://godbolt.org/z/5GczY9K15.  As others have pointed out, even if it was a valid function type `std::function` could still reject it.

Comment: It is called **abominable function type**. It is an incomplete type with no instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `int(int) const` a valid function type in C++23?

Yes, `int(int) const` has always been(even before c++23) a *function type*. Even `auto(int)const->int` is a function type.

This can be seen from [dcl.fct](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct):

> 1. In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
>  D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
>    ref-qualifieropt noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt
> ```
>
> 2. In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
>  D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
>    ref-qualifieropt noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt trailing-return-type
> ```
>
> 3. **A type of either form is a function type.**

(emphasis mine)

This means that both are `auto(int)const->int` as well as `int(int)const` are function type.

```
using type = int(int) const;             //this is a function type
using anothertype = auto(int)const->int; //this is also a function-type
```

Answer (score 4):

By chance I found this example from the [standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#example-4):

> ```
> [Example 4: 
> typedef int FIC(int) const;
> FIC f;              // error: does not declare a member function
> struct S {
>   FIC f;            // OK
> };
> FIC S::*pm = &S::f; // OK
> — end example]
> ```

The section is about the possibility to use an alias to declare but not define a (member) function. Coincidentally, it nicely illustrates the `foo(bar) const` type.

Above `FIC` is an alias for `int(int) const`. Its a function type. There are, however, no functions of that type. You can use it to declare a member inside a class, or declare a pointer to member function, as shown in the lines marked with `OK` respectively. The type of the pointer is `int(S::*)(int)const`.